# Workaround to use slicer values in measures that behave like column calculations in powerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I'm trying to use slicer values as calculated column or something that works like one

I've seen this post

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Slicer-Value-in-Column-Formula/m-p/214892#M95071

but not sure how to proceed with the following case

I have registers from a sort of SCD with ValidStartDate and ValidEndDate

User should be able to set 2 slicers: AnalysisStartDate and AnalysisEndDate

I should be able to count registers based on those two dates, for instance

- how many registers have ValidStartDate between AnalysisStartDate and AnalysisEndDate?
- how many registers have ValidEndDate between AnalysisStartDate and AnalysisEndDate ?

Anyhelp appreciated

Comment: I would recommend to change your question title. Calculated columns can not respond to slicers; it must be a measure.

Comment: well I want something that works like a calculated column... looking for a workaround. I'll add that to the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I managed to get to what i wanted

First you need a "measure" version of the columns you want to use in calculation just using `FIRSTDATE()` for instance -- I think it's very important to create the measure in the same table

To capture slicer value in a measure using something like:

if it has one value, get the value, otherwise use first value (or whatever you want)

```
x Analisis Inicio = IF(HASONEVALUE(TD_FECHAS_INICIO[DT_ANALISIS_INICIO]);VALUES(TD_FECHAS_INICIO[DT_ANALISIS_INICIO]);FIRSTDATE(TD_FECHAS_INICIO[DT_ANALISIS_INICIO].[Date]))
```

Now you can start creating measures which compare both

```
x SW_ES_ALTA = 
IF(
    AND([x Inicio Measure] >= [x Analisis Inicio] 
        ; [x Inicio Measure] <= [x Analisis Fin])
    ;"SI"
    ;"NO"
)
```

and even counts of this last measure

```
x HC_ES_ALTA = COUNTAX(FILTER(ZZ_FLAGS_INMUEBLE;[x SW_ES_ALTA]="SI");ZZ_FLAGS_INMUEBLE[ID_INMUEBLE])
```

Not the easiest path, and probably you can put several of these measures in a single one, but if it works, it works...